# Most efficient way to get a tree object's root node

Tags: performance, design-patterns, tree, root, memory-efficient

I am interested in some design pattern that will give me very fast access from any tree node to the tree root with as little CPU and memory overhead as possible.

Now, to iterate the obvious solutions, and explain why they are inapplicable:

- go down the tree until the root is found - which is what I am currently doing, but as the tree can get quite deep and root access is pretty frequent, that is not an ideal solution, even if mitigating the overhead by caching and reusing the root as much as possible
- store the root node pointer in every node - very fast, but adds a significant memory overhead, as the tree is quite big

Now, if there was only one tree, I could use a singleton, a static class member or any similar approach, however the application has more than one tree, each representing an open project.

Before resorting to searching the root, my design involved only one single **active project** at a time, so I could presume that if any user activity is occurring, it would be targeting the active project, which was a very efficient way to get the particular object's root item.

But now I have a multiple windows application, where each window can have a different active project, and also inter-project communication that can trigger activity inside a project that is not currently active in any editor window. So it is no longer possible to use the "active project pointer" approach.

It seems that I have exhausted all options, but there might be some fancy design pattern which could give me a good compromise?

Answer (score 0):

I went for a solution based on segregating the purpose of different tree nodes.

Most nodes are simply content, but there are also container nodes, which are fairly evenly distributed across the tree.

Container nodes store the tree root, and since they are few and far in between, the memory overhead is minimized. So is the lookup time, as I no longer have to traverse the entire tree until I get to the root, but only down to the nearest container node.

So in a typical usage scenario, this reduces lookup time by 2-3 orders of magnitude, by adding about 1-2% of memory overhead. A more than fair compromise.